# Layout of the site design is not user friendly?

Tags: website-design, page-layout, user-experience

I have developed and running my own website [www.themeswild.com](http://www.themeswild.com) for free html templates, Lots of them saying that the navigation and layout is not user friendly and somebody saying that the site is MFA ( Made for Advertisements ) please help and suggest me that the layout is user friendly or not. and also suggest me some designs & inspirations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Sharavnan and welcome. Please edit your question to meet our [critique guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/682/23061) or your question may be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The navigation sure is confusing.

   - The navigation is all over the place. Took me a while to realize what each navigation element was all about due to that.
   - I'm not saying they should all be in the same place, but the hierachy is totally bonkers.

     - Search bar on the left side
     - Some sort of categories on the top bar on the right
     - Traditional vertical menu on right
     - I might try to position the category dropdown (also maybe the search bar) between the top bar and the grid of templates... or perhaps put the dropdown on the left sidebar.
2. Why are the "download" icon and the eye icon visible in the front page? They don't seem to have any function in this page, right?

   - At about like 990px width you got a breakpoint that throws the right sidebar below the content. This is, I think, the only time that the position of these two icons make sense. [image]
3. I'm not a big fan of the liquid layout that is going on there

   - I generally don't like it, but the biggest issue I guess is the way the template preview images stretch. It's not so great.. There's basically like a sweet spot where the previews look fine, but if the viewport width is bigger or smaller than that, it stretches the image. This happens because the width is flexible but the height is fixed. [image: enter code here]
4. This text on the left sidebar: `Land of your dream website templates. Download 100+ unique and creative html templates for free.`looks visually ok, but I had terrible time reading it because of the vertical spacing.
5. The "Similar templates" section looks a bit weird. I'd
   try how it looks if it just has the template name or maybe if there's some sort of shadow around the images. It just looks kinda bloated and some templates have
   white on the sides, so they kinda blend in with the rest of the site
   in a weird way. To be fair, the whole site looks kinda bloated due to the liquid layout and small amount of spacing.
   [image]
6. So one more point about the liquid layout being terrible. This is what the site looks like with my 2560x1440px resolution, when maximized. Obviously not a resolution that everyone is using, but when you also consider other issues that the liquid layout brings, I think it's a valid point.

   - This small image doesn't do justice to how terrible it looks on the 27" screen [image]
7. I'm also not too fond of those two sidebars. One would be enough.

===================

Edit:

It's looking much better now.

I'm still not super into that liquid layout thing, which can also require a bit too much from your images. In the template page, the preview image at the top can get super large in higher resolutions. On my 1080p 27" mointor it's looking bit blurry. Blurry enough to look weird.

[image]

[image]

I feel that giving the content area `max-width` would not only help with this issue, but make the site look a bit better all-around. The last part is pretty subjective, I'll admit that...

This is what it would look like with a max-width set to 900px:

[image]

The search bar and other stuff you got in the top right can overlap with the main menu if viewport is small enough. On desktop it's not necessarily an issue, but on a tablet in portrait mode, I couldn't click `tutorials` or `contact` because of that.

[image]

Also, the "similar templates"  preview images become super large, when the break point, that pushes sidebar below the content is activated. I'd perhaps try to solve that by placing those preview images side by side at that breakpoint and then back to vertical once the size gets small enough.

[image]

Comment: hey Joonas Thank you so much, for this valuable suggestions, sooner i'll revamp my website with the changes you have mentioned above.

Comment: and the "download" icon and the "eye" icon visible in the front page is to sort by top downloaded templates and top viewed  templates. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks Joonas.. now I revamped my website please guide me now www.themeswild.com

Comment: @SharavnanKv Added an edit at the bottom of my answer. I think that about covers it. There are few spots here and there that could be a bit tighter, but nothing major.